# How to get textbox value in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this in the aspx.cs page and trying to get the value of the text box in my js function. This is not working:

```
result += result.Replace(sOptionText.ToString(), "<input type='text' id=\"txtSS_" + Version + "\" size='10' value=\"" +"\" runat = \"server\" style=\"display:none;\"  />");
```

My js function is here:

```
var sOptionList = "";

var $obj = $('#txtSS_' + VersionID);
if ($('#txtSS_' + VersionID).length > 0)
    sOptionList = $obj.val();
```

I am getting a null value. What am I doing wrong?
Also, wanted to know if my textbox declaration in .cs page is correct. It still shows that the value="" when I firebug it.

Comment: How do you know that the value is not `null` to begin with?

Comment: please update the question if there is a typo

Answer (score 1):

It may be because of an unresolved client ID. Depending on the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) of the page/control, controls will be prefixed with a qualifying value. So the actual ID may be more like `"ctrl0_ctrl1_txtABC"` instead of just `txtABC`.

```
// javascript
var tb = $('#<%= this.txtMyTextbox.ClientID %>');
alert(tb.length);
alert(tb.val());
```

However, you are also building your `input` element as a string rather than instantiating it as a new control. The control is probably not even being executed.

```
// c#
var tb = new TextBox();
tb.ID = "txtABC";

// Add the control to a container on the page. Any server control can be
// a container. This makes it part of the page lifecycle.
this.Controls.Add( tb );
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. $obj is an array. So you have to access an element in the array using $obj[] where  is a number
2. Once you have the element, then use the property .value

So for the first element you would have

```
 sOptionList = $obj[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't doing a document.ready within my click or my jsfunction. So, doing this fixed it:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
       var $Opt = $("#txtSS_" + VersionID).val();
```